# Remove the constraints of an entity during an association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms, easyadmin

I have a problem today with the entities of symfony that blocks me.

I explain my problem.
I have several entities that can be linked together.

My entity B must be associated to a single entity A.
The only problem is that my entity has constraints, a description field is mandatory (NotBlank).

But in some cases, it is not filled in and I don't know why it is still in the database.

This causes that when I want to create a new entity A, I choose an entity B, but symfony will check again the constraints of the entity B and generate a NotBlank error (while the association in reality is possible, the entity B exists but without description) my question is how can temporarily disabled constraints at this time for the famous entity B?

I use EasyAdmin3 backend for manage this crud.

Comment: Sounds like it is either in the entity or in the form. Post your code of both please.

Comment: Not on PC Today, but constraint is on entity with assert annotation